# PDFView controls and WebView interaction

Tags: webview, nsview, pdfview

I have a PDF file displayed in a WebView (internally, it's displayed by PDFView).

How may I take control of the PDF controls that it displays (inside the red rectangle)?

I would like to: 
add more controls to the set, 
enable or disable some of those buttons,
be able to save the file when the user clicks the 'save' button

Thanks.

[image: PDF controls]